# How to remove left/right nav buttons from the super.simple.slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, slider

Hello I have a grid layout with sliders in most of the squares. As you can see below I have two parts to my jquery as I have two different sliders with 2 different effects. In one of the sliders I want to turn off the Nav buttons which I thought would be very simple under the ShowNav option in the jquery however this is not working. Could anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have included a [livelink here](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/newpage.html) which I shall remove after the question is answered for the future posterity of the post.

```
$(function(){

$('.slider').sss({
slideShow : true, // Set to false to prevent SSS from automatically animating.
startOn : 0, // Slide to display first. Uses array notation (0 = first slide).
transition : 800, // Length (in milliseconds) of the fade transition.
speed : 40000, // Slideshow speed in milliseconds.
showNav : true // Set to false to hide navigation arrows.
});


$('.slider2').sss({
slideShow : true, // Set to false to prevent SSS from automatically animating.
startOn : 0, // Slide to display first. Uses array notation (0 = first slide).
transition : 400, // Length (in milliseconds) of the fade transition.
speed : 20000, // Slideshow speed in milliseconds.
showNav : false // Set to false to hide navigation arrows.
});
});
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent static"><div class="slider2">
<img src="slide1.png" height="200" width="200" />
<img src="slide2.png" height="200" width="200" />
<img src="slide3.png" height="200" width="200" />
<img src="slide4.png" height="200" width="200" />
</div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at their code and it looks like they changed "showNav" to "arrows"

```
var settings = $.extend({
slideShow : true,
startOn : 0,
speed : 3500,
transition : 400,
arrows : true
}, options);
```

try changing that options and you should be good to go.